# agreegation or pivot query in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, pivot

I have records

```
ID      zone
1         A
1         B
2         C
2         D
2         E
3         F
```

I want to have result like this

```
ID        zones
1         A/B
2         C/D/E
3         F
```

is there a simple query can do for this in MS sql?

Comment: This isn't really a pivot problem, but more of a [`GROUP_CONCAT` workaround issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/451415/314291)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(ID INT,zone CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(1,'A'),(1,'B'),(2,'C'),
(2,'D'),(2,'E'),(3,'F')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT  t.ID
       ,STUFF((SELECT '/'+ zone
               FROM @TABLE
               WHERE ID = t.ID
               FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).
               value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS Zones

FROM @TABLE t
GROUP BY t.ID
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ Zones ║
╠════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ A/B   ║
║  2 ║ C/D/E ║
║  3 ║ F     ║
╚════╩═══════╝
```

### [`Working SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12ef5/1)